# Center table in LaTeX letter class

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, letters

I am trying to center this table in LaTeX: 
[image: reality] 
so that it stretches to the entire width of the page. I tried several other solutions provided on TeX.SE, but none of them suited my purpose.

M.W.E:

```
\documentclass[16pt]{letter}

\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}%
    \address{White House, \\ Washington D.C \\ The USA}
    \date{}
    \begin{letter}{}%
        \opening{Dear Joe}
         
    Sincerely, \\ \\
    \makebox[\linewidth]{
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c c}
    Founder Name & \makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill}\\
        Founder & Intern Name \\[8ex]% adds space between the two sets of signatures
    \end{tabularx}}
    \end{letter}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: tabularx should only ever be used if it has an X column that allows it to stretch

Comment: also you have a word space at the start of the `makebox` (from `{ ` ) so there is not room to fit a \textwidth wide table. You probably want `{%`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That fixes it! Thank you!